# How does let evaluate a bool value in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm reading [Swift](https://itun.es/tr/jEUH0.l) Programming Language book to get familiar Swift language as many others.

It says that

> In an if statement, the conditional must be a Boolean expression—this means that code such as if score { ... } is an error, not an implicit comparison to zero.

What i understand that condition must evaluate a bool value. Even if it's a integer value, it will not work. But what i don't understand is

```
   if let convertedRank = Rank.fromRaw(3) {
         let threeDescription = convertedRank.simpleDescription() 
}
```

How does this evaluate a bool value. Normally, we use let to create a constant. As implicit conversion isn't possible in Swift, how does `let convertedRank = Rank.fromRaw(3)` evaluate a bool value which is a must for condition ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to Bools, `if` statements [can also take optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_430), with the condition evaluating to whether or not the optional has a  value. This particular construct is called ["optional binding"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_432).

Comment: To be clear, `if-let` is a special case. `let x = something` does not evaluate to an optional: [it has no value.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_72)

Answer (score 2):

`fromRaw()` returns an optional of the type. Because there isn't a Rank for every Int, the function will return either a Rank or nil as a Rank optional. Optionals are the exception to only having Bools in an if condition. If the Optional has a value, it will evaluate as true and if the Optional is nil it will evaluate as false.

Answer (score 2):

The condition in `if`, `where`, etc doesn't actually need to be Bool; it can be any type that implements the `LogicValue` protocol:

```
protocol LogicValue {
    func getLogicValue() -> Bool
}
```

The `getLogicValue()` method is implicitly called when evaluating the conditional statement.

The `if-let` construct, as mentioned in other answers, is a special case for simultaneously testing an Optionals for nil and (if it isn't) unwrapping it at the same time.